# How can I limit the number of returned items in Perl's split?

Tags: perl, parsing, split

I got a problem when I parse a complex file which include thousands of lines.

I already implemented my Perl script like this days ago.

```
 my ($head, $tail) = split /=/, $line;
```

Nearly all my source file `$line` style as below:

```
constant normalLines = <type value>     /*  hello world  */
```

and I can get the output `$tail = /*  hello world  */`

Today I found a bug when I parse the line like this (there are two `=` in the line)

```
constant specialLine = <type value>     /*  hello = world  */
```

But now the output is `$tail = /*  hello`

How can I fix my bug still using `split()` in my code above? I still want the output `$tail = /*  hello = world  */`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the limit parameter to tell [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/functions/split.html) how many parts you want at most:

```
# split /PATTERN/,EXPR,LIMIT

my ($head, $tail) = split /=/, $line, 2;
```

Comment: That's great. I don't know how to describe my question better actually. But you input what i need really. I wish to mark it as my answer right now. But I must waiting another 6 min. haha. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Whenever you have a question about a Perl function, read its documentation. This answer is already in there. :)

Answer (score 2):

@Thilo is exactly right about how you can fix this, but the source of the problem is that you were doing a list assignment in a way that caused list items to be dropped. Doing the split like you had would result in the following list:

```
  ["constant specialLine ", " <type value>     /*  hello ", " world  */"]
```

When you use that in a list assignment, you take the first two values and the rest are thrown away.

Comment: Thanks for your input. That's why I love SOF. Sometime I can receive some nice comments even I already got my answer and get more deeply in my original question here. BTW. I learned a new english word *Nerd*. ;)